# Apigee authentication via stormpath. Is this feasible?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, apigee, stormpath

Currently all users of my web application are authenticated against stormpath. From now on, that web application will need to consume a rest api hosted on Apigee. Here start my doubts.
Apigee grants access to API through oauth2.0. That's great. However i'd like to know wheter I'll be able to keep the current webapp authentication in Stormpath service or not. I'm not an expert in Oauth. Thus, I'm not sure if it's feasible to authenticate in Stormpath and thereafter ask for an AccessToken in Apigee. The WebApplication will have the client credential in order to ask for Access Tokens.
Being straigthforward: Could user be authenticated in a third party service and still get an Oauth Access Token to a Rest API hosted in Apigee ??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Yo @blackjack,

Just a heads up, but Stormpath does support API authentication (via OAuth). If you're using them already, it should be a piece of cake to get working =)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got no answers. It's better not choosing Apigee, I think. No community support. I'll move on.
Thanks anyway.